# Stack and List from System.Collections.Generic not keeping order in asynchronous environment

Tags: c#, list, generics, stack, botframework

I am using a generic List and Stack in a maindialog of a virtual assistant bot (Microsoft). I am using a stack and list to keep track of different dialog names (strings) and I'm using a stack to pop and push dialogs (strings) as needed. This is a fairly asynchronous environment and I think the issue (order not being kept) might be with serialization.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

For example: I have a stack

```
Stack<string> DialogStack  = new Stack<string>();
```

And I'm pushing strings to the stack as follows:

```
DialogStack.Push("dialog_1");
```

Some Async stuff happens..

Then:

```
DialogStack.Push("dialog_2");
// Here I then check the ordering 
DialogStack.Peek(); // I get "dialog_2"
```

Some Async stuff happens and I try to check the order again:

```
DialogStack.Peek(); // I get "dialog_1" instead of "dialog_2"
```

The order of the stack is not being kept. What would be the best approach to ensure that the order is kept ?

Comment: show us the full example please

Comment: is there another push when the second async stuff happens?

Comment: No, a total of 2 pushes happen. The first pushing "dialog_1", the second pushing "dialog_2" and no pops

Comment: do you really push strings? or do you push entire objects into the stack ?

Comment: I push strings.

Comment: Generic collections are not thread safe. Look into ConcurrentStack and ConcurrentQueue instead.

Comment: can you log the time when the pushing and the peeking occurs? might it be that the second peek actually occurs before the second push?

Comment: When you check the stack, don't just call `Peek`. Also check the `Count` property. If `Count` changes, then something somewhere is either pushing or popping items. And, as @MongZhu pointed out, async stuff can be tricky. You might want to write some console output just to prove that things are going onto the stack in the order you think they are.

Comment: The count is correct. I'm sure nothing else is accessing the stack and popping or pushing elements. After every Push  peek to ensure that the element was pushed successfully. At this peek everything is in order, but after some async stuff  (that does not modify the stack) the stack is retrieved from memory(?) and I peek and it's in the wrong order.